# Selenium VBA chrome cannot open website after setting default profile with . SetProfile

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome

I want to get data from a website where I need to log in. If I open the website manually via Chrome, I can log in with my user name and password. If I do the same with chrome via selenium vba, the website requires an extra authentication step that I cannot automate. So I have tried to add profile information to the driver with ".SetProfile". There is a default profile and 5 other profiles in ".../UserData", but none of the latter is my standard profile. So I opted for the default profile. Doing this, Chrome asks me to choose one of the available profiles. After choosing the desired profile (my standard profile, which has already a window open), the script should open the log-in page, but nothing happens. No error message, no new tab or window opening, nothing. I can get to this point by debugging step by step, but after this step, I lose control, cannot do any further steps.
As long as I do not include the ".SetProfile" step, the script works fine, with the mentioned limitation that the website then requires a 2-step authentication.

```
Sub CheckThis(Target, Cancel)
    ......
    With chrome
        .SetProfile "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data", True
        .Start 'here, Chrome asks me to choose a profile and then nothing else happens anymore

        .Get "website.com"
        Set user_email = .FindElementById("login-email")
        user_email.SendKeys ("userName")
        Set siguiente = .FindElementById("login-submit")
        siguiente.Click
        Set Password = .FindElementById("login-password")
        Password.SendKeys ("Password")
        Set iniciar = .FindElementById("login-submit")
        iniciar.Click
        (the rest is irrelevant for the issue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now why it does not work and why it probably cannot work.
This is what I tried:

1. I closed the existing open Chrome window with all its tabs before running the script. After the ".SetProfile" line, Chrome asked me again, which profile I want to use. When I chose my standard profile, the Chrome Window that I had just closed, opened again, but the desired webpage did not open.
2. Then I tried again, this time running the script until ".Start" without the ".SetProfile". This opened an empty Chrome window without any profile, as expected. Then I tried to log in to this instance of Chrome manually with my usual profile. The log-in was rejected after entering my username. Checking the error info, I found that, among others, Google does not allow logging in if the browser is not controlled by a person but by an automatization software which, of course, is the case when I open Chrome from Selenium.
   This means, there seems to be no solution for my problem. Without logging in to my Chrome profile, the web page will always require 2-step authentication, and logging in to a Chrome profile is not possible if Chrome is controlled by VBA.